# Laravel 4: Adding where clause to a join condition

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-4, fluent

It says in the [laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#joins) that it is possible to add where clause on a join, but whenever I try in my code using the where clause, I get the error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::where()`. Anyone knows how to add where clause in a join clause?

Laravel Website Example:

```
DB::table('users')
->join('contacts', function($join)
{
  $join->on('users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
  ->where('contacts.user_id', '>', 5);
})
->get();
```

Code I'm trying to implement:

```
DB::table('users')
->join('contacts', function($join)
{
  $current_date = date('Y-m-d');
  $join->on('users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
  ->where('contacts.effective_date', '>=', $current_date);
})
->get();
```

Comment: your passing wrong variable to where clause try to correct that.

Comment: Okay, updated the variable name, but the problem still remains.

Comment: Try using just > than in your where clause..

Answer (score 12):

if you want add more condition on a `join` add more `$join->on` or `$join->orOn`.

if you want to add a condition to your first select, add it outside join function.

```
DB::table('users')
->join('contacts', function($join)
{
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $join->on('users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id');
})
->where('contacts.effective_date', '>=', $date);
->get();
```

---

**Updated**
In Laravel 4.0 which I think you use, you can't use `where` inside your join closure, but since Laravel 4.1 and above you can have `where` conditions after your join condition. I couldn't find documentation for Laravel 4.1 but **[this is the #join documentation for L4.2 and above](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#joins)**

Comment: I can not use 'on' since it can not be joined using a static date. What I would like to do is filter the result before joining it to other tables , which in effect, will have lesser execution time.

Comment: Also watch out for this one: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3681 the bindings are screwed up when doing this.

Answer (score 7):

Please Check Below Answer

```
DB::table('users')
        ->join('contacts', function($join)
        {
            $join->on('users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
                 ->where('contacts.user_id', '>', 5);
        })
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 4):

Try This solution

```
 DB::table('users')
            ->join('contacts', function($join)
            {
                $current_date = date('Y-m-d');
                $join->on('users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
                     ->where('contacts.effective_date', '>', $current_date)
             ->where('contacts.effective_date', '=', $current_date);

            })
            ->get();
```

Comment: that's the problem. I get an error when I add the where clause as stated in my question above.

Answer (score 3):

```
$current_date = date('Y-m-d');
DB::table('users')
->join('contacts', function($join) use ($current_date)
{
  $join->on('users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
      ->where('contacts.effective_date', '>=', $current_date);
})
->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling $current_date but you decarle $date

```
DB::table('users')
->join('contacts', function($join)
{
  $date = date('Y-m-d');
  $join->on('users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
  ->where('contacts.effective_date', '>=', $date);
})
->get();
```

I don't know if this solve the problem, try it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are sure that you are working with laravel 4.1? I think you are using laravel 4.0 instead of 4.1. Look in your composer.json file.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

Add this just before the `get()` function call

```
->where('contacts.effective_date', '=', $current_date);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$users = DB::table('users')
    ->join('contacts', 'users.id', '=','contacts.user_id')
    ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
    ->select('users.*', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price')->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries please check this link